# Inner Join en EF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Tengo 2 tablas, `Casiller` y `Partes`:

**CASILLER**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PARTES**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una clase donde quiero mapear los resultados:

```
public class mapRequeRollosGet
    {
        public string codi { get; set; }
        public string clie { get; set; }
        public string desc { get; set; }
        public string uni { get; set; }
        public double disp { get; set; }
    }
```

Tengo un numero de `rollo`cualquiera, lo que quiero es con el numero de `rollo` escoger `cod_parte` y `cantidad`de ese rollo (eso es lo facil), una vez que obtenga estos 2 datos, agarrar el `cod_parte`y buscar en la tabla `Partes`, el `cliente`, `descripcion` y `unidad`.

Estoy es lo que llevo hasta ahora:

```
public List<mapRequeRollosGet> getRolloRequeCara(string rol)
 {
    var lista = new List<mapRequeRollosGet>();

    using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
    {
         lista = ctx.Casillers.Where(x => x.rollo == rol)
                              .Select(m => new mapRequeRollosGet
                               {
                                  codi=m.cod_parte,
                                  disp=m.cantidad

                               }).ToList();

      }

       return lista;
 }
```

Aqui escogo el `cod_parte`y `cantidad`de `Casiller`pero no se como agregar la parte que a partir de `cod_parte` escoger los demás datos

**ACTULIZACION**

Como lo primero que me llega es el `rollo`debo obtener `cod_parte` y `cantidad` de la tabla `Casiller`, estoy recuperando el dato asi:

```
    var listaTemp = new List<Casiller>();
    using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
     {
         listaTemp = ctx.Casillers.Where(x => x.rollo == rol)
                                  .ToList();
     }
```

Ahora lo que intento hacer es tratar de recuperar el valor de `cod_parte` para poder mapear la segunda tabla (no se como recuperar el valor):

```
string cod_Rollo = listaTemp.Select(r => r.cod_parte); 
//Esta malo esta forma, lo que quiero es ver en listaTemp
//el valor de cod_parte por ejemplo 5724.42
```

Ya recuperado el valor de `cod_parte` de `listaTemp`poder hacer algo asi:

```
 using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
            {
                lista = ctx.Partes.Where(x => x.cod_parte == cod_Rollo)
                                .Select(m => new mapRequeRollosGet
                                {
                                   codi=cod_Rollo, //cod_parte recuperado
                                   clie=m.cliente,
                                   desc=m.descripcion,
                                   uni=m.unidad,
                                   disp=//disponible o cantidad de listaTemp
                                }).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: Estas seguro que debes ingresar por `Casillers` ? creo que deberias ingresar por `Partes` usando `ctx.Partes.Where(..`  y en esta reflejar la lista de rollos, porque entiendo que la relacion es uno a muchos de Partes -> Casillers

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si y no, no estan relacionados, por que primero obtengo el numero de `rollo`y a partir del numero de `rollo`, buscar el resto de datos, por eso no puedo aplicar al principio (según yo) `ctx.Partes.Where(` puesto que la columna `rollo` no existe en `Partes`

Comment: como mapeas en entity framework estas dos entidades? porque remarco que es una relacion uno a muchos. Tiene que haber una propiedad de navegacion

Comment: @LeandroTuttini estoy haciendolo de una forma, guardar los datos en `var listaTemp = new List<Casiller>();`, existe una forma de acceder al valor de `List["cod_parte"]`(esta mala esta sentencia) pero como hago para buscar un valor en funcion del nombre de la propiedad en que se mapeo? Es que quiero buscar el valor de `cod_parte` y a partir de ese valor ahora si mapear la segunda tabla (`Parte`), no es la mejor manera pero es lo que se me ocurre

Comment: no entiendo que estas planteando, como defines la clase que hereda de  DbContext donde mapeas estas clase? porque deberias relacionanrlas con na propiedad de nevagacion, sabes como hacerlo en entity framework? es mas usas `code first` ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini edito la pregunta, para poder entenderme

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no se como hacerlo y si, uso code first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas usando `entity framework` deberias mapear la navegacion entre las entidades.

[Configure One-to-Many Relationships in EF 6](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Si tienes las entidades

```
public class Casiller
{
   //resto propiedades

   public int cod_parte{ get; set; }
   public Parte Parte { get; set; }
}

public class Parte
{
   public int cod_parte {get;set;}
   //resto propiedades

   public ICollection<Casiller> Casillers { get; set; }
}
```

entonces lo mapeas usando

```
public class xxContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Casiller> Casillers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parte> Partes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parte>().HasKey<int>(s => s.cod_parte);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Casiller>()
                    .HasRequired<Parte>(s => s.Parte)
                    .WithMany(g => g.Casillers)
                    .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.cod_parte);  
    }
}
```

Si ademas quieres puedes mapear la navegacion en el otro sentido

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parte>()
    .HasMany<Casiller>(g => g.Casillers)
    .WithRequired(s => s.Parte)
    .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.cod_parte);
```

La idea con todo esto es que despues puedas hacer

```
using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
{
     lista = ctx.Casillers.Where(x => x.rollo == rol)
                          .Select(m => new mapRequeRollosGet
                           {
                              codi = m.cod_parte,
                              disp = m.cantidad
                              desc = m.Parte.descripcion,
                              uni = m.Parte.unidad
                           }).ToList();

}
```

La navegacion es directa porque tienes las propiedades mapeadas

Answer (score -2):

```
using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
     {
       string rollo = "1478370";
       var query = from c in ctx.Casillers
                   join p in ctx.Partes on c.cod_parte equals p.cod_parte
                   where c.rollo == rollo
                   select new mapRequeRollosGet
                   {
                     codi = c.cod_parte,
                     disp = c.cantidad,
                     clie = p.cliente,
                     uni = p.unidad,
                     desc = p.descripcion
                   };
       List<mapRequeRollosGet> list = query.ToList();
     }
```

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda que explicaras un poco tu respuesta

Comment: @shop350 recuerda evitar comentarios de ese tipo, recuerda que tenemos un [Código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) el cual debe ser seguido, en cuanto a tu respuesta sería buena idea agregaras una explicación ya que las respuestas que son solo código se consideran de "Baja calidad", veo que has dado excelentes respuestas no entiendo porque esta respuesta es la excepción, saludos..

Comment: La respuesta en código resuelve el problema, son doble moral, primero que si explicas demasiado y luego que no explicas nada

Comment: En el grupo de inglés una respuesta en código se marcó como correcta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables

Comment: La respuesta que enlazas es de 2014, cuando las normas del sitio estaban aún por definir. Actualmente se espera que las respuestas sean de calidad y con una explicación al menos mínima de cual era el problema del op y como el código resuelve su problema. Puedes leer [este post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/15301) que lo explica mejor, y si tienes alguna duda puedes usar meta para plantearla.

Comment: Además, @shop350, este sitio no tiene que ver con el inglés. Lo que es válido alli puede no serlo aqui y al revés. Mira las normas en [answer] y  [help]  para más info.. Un saludo